# adding the values from gui to the database table

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to update a table in the database where i m accepting fees from the students and maintaining the record of the amount received, total amount received, and the mode of payment etc.
my code is as follows:

```
private void pay_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hostel";
    String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,"root","17121990");
            System.out.println("connected!");

            String firstname=pay_enter_firstname.getText();
            String lastname=pay_enter_lastname.getText();

            String amt=pay_enter_amt.getText();
            int amount=Integer.parseInt(amt);
            String day=pay_enter_date.getText(); 
            String cheque_no=pay_enter_chequeno.getText();
            String mode=pay_enter_mode.getText();
            int totalamount=10000;               
            int bal_amt=totalamount-amount;
            String remark=pay_enter_remark.getText();          
            int id = Integer.parseInt(pay_enter_id.getText());

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment");





            if(rs.next())
           {
                stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment");

              while(rs.next())
                {



              int temp =rs.getInt(1);

              if (temp ==id)
              {
                  int amtrecvd2= rs.getInt(2);
                  bal_amt=totalamount- (amtrecvd2+amount);
                  String updt = "UPDATE payment SET Amountreceivd="+(amtrecvd2+amount)+",lastamtreceived="+amount+",dte='"+day+"', balance_amt ="+bal_amt+" WHERE id ="+temp+";" ;
                  Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
                  int result = stmt1.executeUpdate(updt);
              }

                }
           }

             if(!rs.next())
            {
                String str=" INSERT INTO payment(id, firstname,lastname,Amountreceivd,dte,lastamtreceived,Creditcashcheque,"
                   + "cheque_no,balance_amt,totalamount,Remark) VALUES ("+id+",'"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"',"+amount+",'"+day+"',"+amount+",'"+mode+"','"+cheque_no+"',"+ bal_amt+","+totalamount+",'"+remark+"')";
                Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();

                int result=stmt1.executeUpdate(str);
                panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);
            }


               panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);



    con.close();
    }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Initially when i add new values i get it properly but when i am trying to update an existing row i get the error that i m making a duplicate entry for primary key id.

what condition should i check so that i come to know that the result set is not having that particular id value and new person is paying the fee??

Comment: You added the duplicate entry foe the table which has Primary key for the Column.. just show the postion where exception throws, so taht we can only focus for that area.\

Comment: Error throws in this statement.   String str=" INSERT INTO payment(id, firstname,lastname,Amountreceivd,dte,lastamtreceived,Creditcashcheque,"
                   + "cheque_no,balance_amt,totalamount,Remark) VALUES ("+id+",'"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"',"+amount+",'"+day+"',"+amount+",'"+mode+"','"+cheque_no+"',"+ bal_amt+","+totalamount+",'"+remark+"')";
                Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();

Answer (score 1):

This condition:
`if(!rs.next())`
is being checked outside the while loop. This condition is always true and will try to insert a record even if update has taken place.
To avoid this, i suggest using a flag variable. Once an update has occurred, set the value of this flag to 1.
Check if it has been made 1 instead of `if(!rs.next())` and go inside.

Answer (score 1):

You're two `if` statements are colliding...

```
// If this is true...
if(rs.next()) {
    // ...
    // Looping till the it's false...
    while(rs.next()) {
        // ....
    }
 }

 // Will mean that this is false...
 if(!rs.next())
```

You should be using an `else`

```
if(rs.next()) {
    // ...
    while(rs.next()) {
        // ....
    }
 } else {...}
```

**Updated**

After an enlightening conversion with Aashray (thanks), we've concluded that your logic is broken

Rather then manually trying to find the record manually by match the id's let the SQL database do it for you.

Instead of....

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment");
```

You should be using...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment where id = " + id);
```

This will return a `ResultSet` that is either empty (no matches) or with (hopefully) one row.

From there, calling `rs.next()` will now let you branch of between an update or insert correctly.

```
private void pay_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hostel";
    String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "17121990");
        System.out.println("connected!");

        String firstname = pay_enter_firstname.getText();
        String lastname = pay_enter_lastname.getText();

        String amt = pay_enter_amt.getText();
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(amt);
        String day = pay_enter_date.getText();
        String cheque_no = pay_enter_chequeno.getText();
        String mode = pay_enter_mode.getText();
        int totalamount = 10000;
        int bal_amt = totalamount - amount;
        String remark = pay_enter_remark.getText();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(pay_enter_id.getText());

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment where id = " + id);

        if (rs.next()) {
            int amtrecvd2 = rs.getInt(2);
            bal_amt = totalamount - (amtrecvd2 + amount);
            String updt = "UPDATE payment SET Amountreceivd=" + (amtrecvd2 + amount) + ",lastamtreceived=" + amount + ",dte='" + day + "', balance_amt =" + bal_amt + " WHERE id =" + id + ";";
            Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
            int result = stmt1.executeUpdate(updt);
        } else {
            String str = " INSERT INTO payment(id, firstname,lastname,Amountreceivd,dte,lastamtreceived,Creditcashcheque,"
                            + "cheque_no,balance_amt,totalamount,Remark) VALUES (" + id + ",'" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "'," + amount + ",'" + day + "'," + amount + ",'" + mode + "','" + cheque_no + "'," + bal_amt + "," + totalamount + ",'" + remark + "')";
            Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();

            int result = stmt1.executeUpdate(str);
            panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);
        }

        panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);

        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If it enters `if(rs.next())`,it will not go into the `else` part and if there hasn't been an update done, the insert statement should be executed.

Comment: How can it go into the "update" section if there are no results?  That's the point isn't?

Comment: No what he's trying to do is, if its an existing customer, just update. If its a new customer, insert a new record.

Comment: See his query. There is no `where` clause. Its returning more than one record. The `if` checks only if there is a record, not if it matches the id.

Comment: ya i know what you mean... :)

Comment: @Aashray Nice pick up on the "where" statement (or lack there of) :P

Comment: thanks a lot guys.. i got it.. I made a mistake in the logic.. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think this may help you
```

private void pay_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hostel";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

```
    con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,"root","17121990");
    System.out.println("connected!");

    String firstname=pay_enter_firstname.getText();
    String lastname=pay_enter_lastname.getText();

    String amt=pay_enter_amt.getText();
    int amount=Integer.parseInt(amt);
    String day=pay_enter_date.getText(); 
    String cheque_no=pay_enter_chequeno.getText();
    String mode=pay_enter_mode.getText();
    int totalamount=10000;               
    int bal_amt=totalamount-amount;
    String remark=pay_enter_remark.getText();          
    int id = Integer.parseInt(pay_enter_id.getText());

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                          ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment");





    if(rs.next())
   {
        stmt = con.createStatement(
                          ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                          ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, lastamtreceived FROM payment");

      while(rs.next())
        {



      int temp =rs.getInt(1);

      if (temp ==id)
      {
          int amtrecvd2= rs.getInt(2);
          bal_amt=totalamount- (amtrecvd2+amount);
          String updt = "UPDATE payment SET Amountreceivd="+(amtrecvd2+amount)+",lastamtreceived="+amount+",dte='"+day+"', balance_amt ="+bal_amt+" WHERE id ="+temp+";" ;
          Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
          int result = stmt1.executeUpdate(updt);
      }

        }
   }
    else
    {
        String str=" INSERT INTO payment(id, firstname,lastname,Amountreceivd,dte,lastamtreceived,Creditcashcheque,"
           + "cheque_no,balance_amt,totalamount,Remark) VALUES ("+id+",'"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"',"+amount+",'"+day+"',"+amount+",'"+mode+"','"+cheque_no+"',"+ bal_amt+","+totalamount+",'"+remark+"')";
        Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();

        int result=stmt1.executeUpdate(str);
        panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);
    }


       panel_feesframe.setVisible(false);
```

con.close();
}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | NumberFormatException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: `rs.next()` is being called twice so the 1st value in the 0th position is ignored.

Comment: now this will work only for the 1st row returned. It won't check the 2nd,3rd and so on.